# I need guidance about permissions in Xenforo

Tags: xenforo

How to only first superAdmin access to a group permissions example(signature permissions), but other admin and superAdmin no access to that (signature permissions)

for example, first SuperAdmin with id = 1 only see and access some permissions and can change it,
and other superAdmin cannot see this permission.

Answer (score 1):

Super admins are defined in the `library/config.php` file:

`$config['superAdmins'] = '1,2,3';`

1, 2 and 3 being three different user IDs.

Comment: It was not my intention.
=> for just access to specify permission!

Comment: @AleX I believe you can assign the permission by editing the admin user permissions. It has been awhile since I last checked it out.